# Live ID Web Authentication on Azure

Tags: authentication, azure, cloud, live

I have a Silverlight application and want to use it, on Azure with Live ID web autentication.

Now I search for a good tutorial or solution to use the Live Id Web Authentication in a Cloud application, to use it on Azure.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

As far I understand your problem, Live ID authentication isn't different on Windows Azure (considering your get a `WebRole`) compared to regular ASP.NET. Applying regular methods should work, see http://blog.webjak.net/2008/08/13/silverlight-windows-live-id/